# How to give conditions when using HashMap

Tags: java

QUESTION:

Write a program to print all the unique characters in a given sentence. 
If unique characters are not found print "No unique characters".
If unique characters are found print those characters as shown in sample output.

MY CODE:

```
public class Unique {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> list = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        if(!Pattern.matches(".*[a-zA-z]+.*[a-zA-z]",s)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Sentence");
        } else {
            for(Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
                if (list.containsKey(c)) {
                    list.put(c, list.get(c) + 1);
                } else {
                    list.put(c, 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Unique characters:");
            for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e: list.entrySet()) {
                if((int)e.getValue() == 1)   
                   System.out.println(e.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to give condition for  "No unique characters" when unique characters are not found.

Comment: if all values in `list` are >1, then there are no unique chars

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check if the map contains any value mapped to 1, if so - there is at least one unique character. If the opposite is true, there are no unique characters. With lambdas, this can be done in one line, e.g.:

```
        if (list.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v == 1)) {
            System.out.println("Unique characters:");
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : list.entrySet()) {
                if ((int) e.getValue() == 1)
                    System.out.println(e.getKey());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No unique characters");
        }
```

Please note the (int) cast is not necessary (as per your code), as due to unboxing, e.getValue is already an int, so this:

```
if ((int) e.getValue() == 1)
```

can with no side effects become this:

```
if (e.getValue() == 1)
```

It would also be good if the list variable was renamed to map to avoid confusion.